# array_search wrong argument datatype

Tags: php, arrays

I am playing around with this:

```
$sort = array('t1','t2');

function test($e){
    echo array_search($e,$sort);
}

test('t1');
```

and get this error:

```
Warning: array_search(): Wrong datatype for second argument on line 4
```

if I call it without function like this, I got the result 0;

```
echo array_search('t1',$sort);
```

What goes wrong here?? thanks for help.

Comment: result 0; is ok, please notice that $sort[0] = 't1';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in PHP have **function scope**. The variable `$sort` is not available in your function `test`, because you have not passed it in. You'll have to pass it into the function as a parameter as well, or define it inside the function.

<sub>You can also use the `global` keyword, but it is really not recommended. Pass data explictly.</sub>

Comment: Ok,, I think this just slipped my mind today. thanks for help. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the array as a parameter! Because the functions variables are different from globals in php!

Here is the fixed one:

```
$sort = array('t1','t2');

function test($e,$sort){
    echo array_search($e,$sort);
}

test('t2',$sort);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly access global variables from inside functions.
You have three options:

```
function test($e) {
  global $sort;

  echo array_search($e, $sort);
}

function test($e) {
  echo array_search($e, $GLOBALS['sort']);
}

function test($e, $sort) {
  echo array_search($e, $sort);
} // call with test('t1', $sort);
```

Answer (score 0):

take the $sort inside the function or pass $sort as parameter to function test()..

For e.g.

```
function test($e){
$sort = array('t1','t2');
    echo array_search($e,$sort);
}

test('t1');


----- OR -----
$sort = array('t1','t2');
function test($e,$sort){

    echo array_search($e,$sort);
}

test('t1',$sort);
```